# How to display elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm still learning Java and I was wondering how can I access an element of an array? For example, I have this array:

```
private int[] employeeNum={5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 1302850, 7580489};
```

And I want to display the number "450125" while using a for loop. What should I do?
Also, if you have a better method rather than a for loop,
please feel free to put it;
it would be much appreciated.
I'll put in the for loop I'm using just in case :

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the hours worked by employee number " +
    employeeNum[i] + ":");
}
```

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays; System.out.println( Arrays.toString(employeeNum) );`

Comment: Do you want to display 45202125 or do you want to display the second element in your array?  these are two very different questions.

Comment: By "access an element of an array", do you mean "find a specific value in an array"?

Comment: Your accessing array elements in your for loop. employeeNum[i] is getting the element at index i.

Comment: DwB: display the second element in the array.

Comment: Sizik: Yes, sorry for not being more specific :(

Comment: mbiokyle: I do understand the I´m accessing the index, I just put it in since I´m still not sure exactly what to do.

Comment: employeeNum[1] to access the second element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to display the second element in an array, you simply need to do this:
`arrayName[indexNumber]`
In your case, you would need to use this syntax:
`employeeNum[1]`
An index (such as "indexNumber" and "1" used above) is simply an address. The former being a variable representing a number, and the latter being a number. Imagine you had ten houses on the right side of a given street. If you were to explain to someone else how to get to the second house on the right, you would say something like this:
`houses[1]`
Why did I put a '1' instead of a '2'?
Because, in programming, you start counting at '0' instead of '1'.
I hope this helps. Be sure to up-vote those comments that are helpful, and mark the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Redington You're welcome. Please be sure to up-vote those answers that you find answer to original question well. Not just in questions you have asked, but also in other question threads as well.